# Wordpress: Unlimitet Posts on specific Page

Tags: php, wordpress, limit, posts

for general, the limit of posts per page in my wordpress blog is set to 3 Post.

But on one specific Page i need to show unlimited Posts. Anyone knows how to do this.. i don't get it.

The code on this specific Page (projects) right now

```
<div id="content" class="fullProjects clearfix full grid">                                  
                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>                                         
                    <?php the_content(); ?>                                                     
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The 3 Post limit is set in the wordpress admin - backend - not by code.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can over-ride the settings from the admin page programmatically. You're going to need to tweak your query, though, and over-ride the loop. I think something like this will work:

```
global $wp_query;

$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );
query_posts( $args );

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

(I'm putting this together from a couple of different man pages, so it might not be perfect; but it should point you in the right direction)

Effectively, you're making a new query for posts (the `query_posts` call). You're passing it a new set of parameters, created from the existing ones via the `array_merge`; and you're explicitly setting `posts_per_page` to -1, which should turn off the limit for the number of posts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont know if this will work for me.. the limitation of 3 posts per page is ok, because on another page (news) i only want to have 3 posts displayed.. but on the projects site, i want to have unlimited posts..

Comment: @user3599221 - there's two ways you can deal with that. You can have a separate template for each section; or you can have a single template for both, but add a check to see if you're on the projects page - depending on which page you're on, you run a different piece of code.